# Add Directory EasyPHP Devserver 16

Tags: php, directory, easyphp

I recently upgraded EasyPHP 14 to 16.

I liked this new feature "WORKING DIRECTORIES", I try use a special directory in my computer, folders of Dropbox and Google Drive, but anyone work.

**Ps:** Use a *"normal"* folder work perfectly.

> Error: 403 Forbidden
>   Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /edsa-testing/test.php on this server.

Answer (score 0):

> Just edit the file: ***apache/httpd.conf***.
>   Search < Directory > and edit:

```
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Works perfectly in Devservers!
Tested in EasyPHP and WAMP.

Comment: Please consider removing all that unnecessary formatting from your post. If everything is highlighted, nothing is highlighted. And even then, you don't need highlighting with an answer this short and clear. Also, the "Solution:" header is completely needless: answers on Stack Overflow always contain he "Solution".